# Getting previous line in Bash after new command?

Tags: bash

In a Bash terminal, I often type a command and realize that I needed to sudo that command.  I hit the up arrow to get the previous command and then backtrack to the beginning type sudo and enter.

Is there any way to type sudo, then press a key to pull down the previous command after sudo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: you can use ["history expansion"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction), and write `!!`:

```
$ foo
bash: foo: command not found
$ sudo !!
sudo foo                             <-- it prints out the expanded command
bash: sudo: command not found        <-- and then runs it
```

Comment: great! now please run `apt-get install foo` and `apt-get install sudo`. :)

Comment: @Kaz: I ran this on a Windows box, which has no need for `sudo`, and *certainly* no need for `foo`. I considered SSHing into a handy Linux box and running a command that actually requires root access, like `touch /etc/shadow` or something, but then I decided this way was more fun. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo !!
```

`!!` denotes the previous command

I strongly recommend to visit [CommandlineFu](http://www.commandlinefu.com) which offers a lot of tips and tricks similar to this answer.

**One word of caution:** if you have `HISTIGNORE` set like I do, only those commands *not* ignored can be invoked again this way.